# How to erase a cursor's data completely to prevent memory leak?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cursor

I'm working on this android app that uses the cursor multiple times, but it seems to throw an CursorWindowAllocationExecption. I researched this error, and know that this error is due to the overflow in memory from a cursor. So, After each use of the cursor, I close the cursor with:

```
 try{
    c.close();
    }
    finally{
        c.close();
    }
```

It was said that using finally is best when trying to close the cursor, and I know putting c.close into the try statement should include the usage of the cursor, but to be honest, I just want the cursor to close regardless.So I'll use the cursor in a block of code, then I'll close it before the next usage. I even close the data base to be sure the data is cut off. I then open the database back up, and use the same cursor to retrieve different data from the data base. This method works through 3 blocks of code, but when it gets to the 4th block of code, it throws the cursor exception. I've went through many similar post, and everyone suggested the same thing(to be sure the cursor in closed). This is why I wrote excessive code such as the try and finally statements, and the database closing statement. I'm trying to avoid posting the code, because then I would have to post hundreds of lines of code to make it useful. I'm hoping the information I posted is enough to understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try/Catch isn't your answer as you're not throwing errors while closing the cursor. You're throwing errors while trying to use it. That's why your code has no effect... you're asking for it to do something when you throw an error that's never thrown.

Since your problem isn't directly caused by trying to use the cursor, but rather trying to use a bad cursor, then testing for the exception that you are throwing won't help either.

You'll have to find why the exception is being thrown in the first place.